# supremum equals to infumum

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:

What can you say about the set M if sup M = inf M.

I know that supremum is the lowest upper bound and infumum is the biggest lower bound. But I cant figure out what you can say about the set M. And we only had one lession about supremum and infumum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume $a,b\in M$ with $a<b$. What can you say about $\inf M$ compared to $a$? What about $\sup M $ compared to $b$? What does that tell about $\inf M$ compared to $\sup M$?

Comment: Sorry but it did not help that much. I have been studying now for 7 hours so the brain does not work properly: P I think I need to rest a little while and try to solve the this after dinner. Thanks anyway! I can return if I did not manage to solve it /Fred

Comment: i could not solve it. I think i need to read more about infumum and supremum. Do you know any good sites?

Answer (score 2):

You know that for *any* $x \in M$, we have $\inf M \leq x \leq \sup M$, by definition of upper and lower bounds (not necessarily *least* upper or *greatest* lower bound). Now, if $\inf M = \sup M$, what does that say about the possible values of $x$?

Comment: Sorry but i havent sold it yet :/ i already knew that you wrote but i did stuck at "Now, if infM=supM, what does that say about the possible values of x?" and what i can say about the set M

Comment: @Fred Discarding any talk about bounds an such, and assuming we just have three numbers $a, b$ and $c$. If $a \leq b \leq c$, and $a = c$, then what can we say about the value of $b$?